# Should 2 different MySql databases from 2 different applications be joined together if the 2 apps are merging into 1?

Tags: architecture, database

**This is a question about software architecture, not databases.**

I currently have 2 completely separate web applications, call them A and B for simplicity. They are on their own machines, with their own databases and web servers. My job is to integrate these 2 applications together (how I'm doing that from the front/backend is irrelevant here).

My scenario when it comes to the database is this: previously apps A and B were separate, but now B is being treated as a module, and will be used inside of A. To the user, it will seem like there is only one application. Behind the scenes though, is it best practice to keep the databases separate, or is it best for app A's database to completely absorb the tables from app B's database and just create one, very large database?

The data isn't related between the two applications, so to me it makes sense to keep the 2 databases separate since B is acting as it's own module still, regardless of whether it's a part of app A or not. What do companies that have a large application do? Do they create a new database for every large component of their software or do they keep it all in one place?

Comment: It depends. What are the reasons for merging vs not merging in your context?

Answer (score 0):

> What do companies that have a large application do? Do they create a new database for every large component of their software or do they keep it all in one place?

This is more dependent on how the applications in question evolved over time than any particular design strategy.

Most applications have always been a single application that gets extended with new functionality over time. With that kind of evolution, it is natural to use a single database.

In the case where two applications get merged, there is more variability because it then depends on what is seen as better, also in economic terms if you factor in development, maintenance and system administration. If the databases can remain logically separated but  be hosted on the same database server, then that is probably the best option in both development and server administration perspectives. But you also have to factor things like user-administration in there and how the merging of that affects the other tables.